# any suggestions on shortening this python code?

Tags: python

I have created a program which rolls a dice according to the amount of sides that the user enters. Here is my code:

```
def var():

    import random

    dicesides = int(input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: "))
    script(dicesides, random)

def script(dicesides, random):

    if dicesides == 4:
        dice4 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice4)

    elif dicesides == 6:
        dice6 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice6)

    elif dicesides == 12:
        dice12 = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice12)

    elif dicesides != 4 or dicesides != 6 or dicesides != 12:
        print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        var()

    repeat = str(input("Repeat? Simply put yes or no : "))

    if repeat == "yes":
        var()
    else:
        quit()

var()
```

is there a way for this to be shortened?

Thanks

Comment: This is better suited to **http://codereview.stackexchange.com/**.

Comment: better suited for: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify all three of those cases into one block because they all have the exact same action.

```
def script(dicesides, random):
    if dicesides in [4,6,12]:
        dice = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice)
    else:
        print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        var()
```

Whenever you see repeated patterns in your source code, you can usually extract them into a single block.

Answer (score 2):

The whole program (especially without the recursion loop between `var` and `script` and the implied bombardment of the callstack. Although your calls are in tail position, this makes no difference in python):

```
from random import randint

while True:
    sides = int(input('Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12:'))
    if sides in (4, 6, 12):
        print('{}-sided die, score {}'.format(sides, randint(1, sides)))
    else:
        print('That number is invalid.')
    if input('Repeat? ') != 'yes':
        break
```

Or the code-golf version of the whole program:

```
(lambda f,r:f(f, r))((lambda f,r:f(f,r)if((lambda r,i:
print('{}-sided die, score {}'.format(i,r.randint(1,i)
)if i in(4, 6,12)else'That number is invalid.')) (r, (
lambda:int(input('Please enter the amount of sides yo'
'u want the dice that is being thrown to have. The di'
'ce sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: ')))()),input(''
'Repeat? '))[1]=='yes'else None),__import__('random'))
```